# Qt Creator adding files to C++ project issue

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a (possibly noob) question regarding adding files to a C++ Qt Creator project.

I right-click, to `Add New...`, either `c++ class` or `.cpp` or `.h` file. The file is created in my project folder, and is added in the `.pro` file. The problem is that it is not added in the `Projects` panel, and when opening the file I get this warning on top of text editor: `Warning: This file is not part of any project. The code model might have issues parsing this file properly.`

The file(s) is added as it was supposed to, if I shut down Qt Creator and then open it again.

As an example (minus the warning) I attach the following picture, for file `asd.cpp`.

[image]

I have searched the web and found some answers but none seem to be relevant to my issue. They refer to a `CMakeLists.txt` file (which I can't find btw), but I am using qmake in this project not cmake.

Any help??

Comment: Where did you right click to add? Try right-clicking the "Sources" folder.

Comment: I have tried both the "sources" and "header" folder for the respective file, as well as the project folder. Same behavior to all of them.

Comment: Make sure you don't have duplicate files and the wrong file is open. Can you build?

Comment: Yes. No duplicate files, and it builds successfully with and without cleaning the project.

Answer (score 1):

The `pro` file is a text file that you can open in Qt Creator or any text editor. It contains the list of files belonging to the project like this:

```
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        MainWindow.cpp

HEADERS  += MainWindow.h

FORMS    += MainWindow.ui
```

You can manually add your `h` files to `HEADERS` and `cpp` files to `SOURCES`. the `\` character at the end means to treat next line as a continuation of the current one so you can put each file on its own line.

Comment: As I said in OP, the file is added in `.pro` file. It's not missing there.